# Reload IMAP folder list in K-9 mail

Tags: k9-mail

Recently I changed the folder structure of my E-Mail account, actually merging a lot of them. K-9 didn't realize the changes. It neither added new new folders nor removed those, no longer existing.

Pressing the refresh button in folders view seems only to refresh the mails, rather that the folders.

How can I achieve a re-read of the account's folder list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the list of folders by clicking on the folder icon next to the IMAP account listed under the Accounts view. That's your list of folder's you'd like to update. Tap the three dots in the lower right. There should be an item called "refresh folder list."

Comment: Well, to my shame, that was too obvious for me to see it. Many thanks Jacob

Comment: Had the same issue, figured it out and couldn't leave you hanging.